# Can a solved Sudoku game have an invalid region if all rows and columns are valid?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, puzzle, latin-square, sudoku

Given a $9 \times 9$ solved Sudoku game with $3 \times 3$ regions, is it possible that one (or more) of the regions are invalid if all rows and columns are valid (i.e. have a unique sequence of $1-9$)?

Comment: By definition, if it's a solved Sudoku then all rows, columns, and regions are valid.

Comment: Given a random $9 \times 9$ Latin square (which is the same thing as a Sudoku grid filled with the digits 1 through 9 such that all rows and columns are valid), there is a 99.99988% chance that at least one of the regions will be invalid. See https://oeis.org/A107739/list (number of $9 \times 9$ Sudoku grids: 6.7 sextillion), https://oeis.org/A002860/list (number of Latin squares: 5.5 octillion).

Comment: This question seems (to some extent) related: [Can a sudoku with valid columns and rows be proved valid without evaluating every 3x3 inside it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2020343)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, it can happen that *all* $3 \times 3$ regions are invalid:

\begin{array}{|ccc|ccc|ccc|} \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks! Given this special case where all are invalid, is there any other case?

Comment: @dragonfly Swap rows 2 and 4, and rows 3 and 7. The three top regions are now valid, while the rest are not.

Comment: Permutating the numbers $1$ to $9$ in this example arbitarily gives other solutions, but there will be tons of further solutions. An interesting question would be : What is the probability that a random $9\times 9$-Latin square has the desired property ? And further : What is the probability that exactly $k$ regions are invalid ($k\in [0,9])$ ?

Comment: Concerning other cases: if two regions in the same row are valid, then all three are, and dually for columns. On the other hand, any pattern of valid and invalid regions that obeys this rule is possible to realize. This, and much more, can be found at https://mathoverflow.net/q/129143 .